# Start and configure Solace with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, solace

Is it really impossible to start solace via a docker-compose.yml and create the message vpn configuration directly after startup?

If I start the solace service in the docker-compose.yml via the

```
command: sh -c /mnt/disks/solace/entrypoint.sh
```

My entrypoint.sh looks like this

```
echo "starting entrypoint.sh"
/mnt/disks/solace/configure-vpn.sh & /usr/sbin/boot.sh
```

Then solace and the configure-vpn.sh are started.

configure-vpn.sh

```
echo "Sleeping 20 before run cli command"
sleep 40
echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! cli !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
/usr/sw/loads/currentload/bin/cli -A -es /mnt/disks/solace/configure-vpn.cli
```

But the cli command never ends and I can't log in via the solace webconsole (Timeout of 30000ms exceeded).

If the command /usr/sbin/boot.sh is entered as a docker-compose command then we have also the problem that no login on solace-gui is possible. It gives after 30s a timeout.

Comment: if you skip the entrypoint.sh provided by the Solace container, won't this prevent the broker to start up ? 

Shouldn't the configuration of the container be in your docker compose script, using CURL to interact with SEMP v2 APi ?

Comment: There is no entry point.sh provided by the Solace container. At least I didn't find one. There is only the /usr/sbin/boot.sh

Comment: Ok, so maybe put /usr/sbin/boot.sh : so that it starts the broker
Then you configure script could interact with the broker once it's running.

Comment: well, maybe boot.sh won't give the hand back, unless you run it in the background (with &), the configure it, and then put it back to foreground fg %1 (so that docker still see a process running)

Comment: But, then changing your configuration would mean build new docker images.
Won't it be better to automate the creation using CI/CD, and use the REST API to make your configurations changes ?